Cannot use git commands in gitlab CI's repository
I'm implementing a gitlab job that uses astyle to fix code formatting and then git diff to check if modifications have been made (and fail the job if so). Here's what it looks like
# Code formatting using astyle 
astyle:
  variables:
    SRC_FOLDER: "astyle"
  stage: format
  rules:
    - changes: 
      - ${SRC_FOLDER}/**/*
  script:
    - pwd; ls -la
    - cd ${SRC_FOLDER}
    - astyle --options=code-format.cfg --recursive "src/*.c,*.cpp,*.h"
    - if ! (git diff --color --exit-code); then echo "Code formatting check failed"; exit 1; fi

The pipeline is executed on a alpine linux Docker image with git installed but when "git diff" is executed, I get the error "warning: Not a git repository". I've added the "pwd; ls -la" commands to check but when they are executed they show me the right path and the .git folder so I don't know what the problem is. I've tried to look for this problem but all the answers I've found were people that forgot to cd into the repository. I also know I'm in the right directory because "cd ${SRC_FOLDER}" does not give an error and it can only be the case if I'm in the right directory
I'm in a custom gitlab instance so the configuration might be the problem but I don't know what to look for in this case

"I've added the "pwd; ls -la" commands to check but when they are executed they show me the right path and the .git folder…" You run pwd; ls -la before cd; it looks like after cd you're not in a git repository. Run pwd; ls -la immediately before git commands.

cd goes into "astyle" which is a subfolder of the repository (I've tried). I expect git to work from anywhere inside a repository but maybe that's not the case in this context. Anyone knows anything about this ?

I did (useless text because SO wants comments to be at least 15 characters long)

"I also know I'm in the right directory because "cd ${SRC_FOLDER}" does not give an error and it can only be the case if I'm in the right directory" There is another possibility: if ${SRC_FOLDER} is empty simple cd goes home without any error. BTW I'm not sure — does GitLab CI run every command in script: in a separate shell? In that case the effect of cd is simply discarded for the next command.

I've checked and tested: when git diff is executed, bash is in the astyle subfolder of the repository but git still insists I'm not in a repository. $SRC_FOLDER is not empty, everything goes as expected except for git diff which fails with the aforementioned error

I finally found the solution by executing git status in a before_script: Apparently the user that clones the repository inside the runner and the user that actually runs the commands aren't the same which makes git panic. When using git diff in a job this results in the "not a git repository" error but in the before script, git status actually explains this and suggests the following fix:
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/builds/reds-general/cicd-knowledge'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory <repository_path>

Applying the suggested command in the before script fixes the problem
